# Apache and MySQL not shutting down after Server2Go shutdown

Tags: webserver, portability, embeddedwebserver, server2go

I am using [Server2Go](http://www.server2go-web.de/), which can run from a CD with no installation.

When I start it it loads Apache and MySQL, and opens a browser (I am using [Firefox Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable)).

After I close the browser window the Server2Go instance shuts down, but leaves the Apache and MySQL processes running.

Thanks